# Send email from IIS on some action

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, email

Is there a way to send email on, let's say, application pool of some site stop? Or on IIS restart. So that I want see if something happened on remote server by receiving email, is there a method to do that with standard windows server tools?

Version: Windows Server 2008 Standard.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows Server 2008 there is an option to generate email alerts when specific events occurs.

In *Event Viewer* go to *Windows Logs* and right click on the event you want to monitor and select *"Attach Task to this event"*. A wizard will guide you through the procedure.

You can enable/disable specific events regarding the application pool under "Advanced Settings" of the specific application pool you want to monitor.

Comment: Thank you for the answer..Yes, i saw that possibility, but there are no events from IIS displayed. My problem was that somehow AppPool stopped and didnt restart automatically, and i knew nothing about that until i opened the IIS management panel. And AppPool's "stop" is not displayed in Application section of event viewer(there are just critical errors of IIS as i saw).

Comment: Probably you'll have to enable logging of these events in "Advanced Settings" of the app pool: http://blogs.iis.net/ganekar/archive/2008/12/12/iis-7-0-application-pool-recycles-log-a-event-in-windows-event-log.aspx

Comment: ..Strange, enabled it for manual recycling(even restarted the site to be sure that changes are made), recycled the pool, opened the event viewer->Windows Logs->Application -nothing is logged.

Comment: Maybe to first recycle of the app pool enabled the option. Try to recycle it a second time.

Comment: wow, what a pain in the ass. I'm running like 20 apps. It would be way easier to put a heartbeat script on  some other server to check HTTP codes for each site and email you when broken.